# JavaScript form for users

Tags: javascript, html, forms, events, onsubmit

I need help with this
So I created a form but I want an alert message to pop up with a message when the user clicks on the check box. How do I use the onsubmit event to do that?

The output should look like this when a new user fills the form.[new user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU3nY.png)
and it should look like this when a returning user fills the form.
[Returning user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZHqx.png)

This is my code but I couldn't use the onsubmit event with it

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="uname"> Enter Name: </label> <br> <br>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" onblur="myFunction()" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" required> <br> <br> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="uemail">Enter Email: </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="uemail" name="usermail" onblur="myFunction()" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" required>
    </table>
    <br>
         <label>Write question below:</label>
         <br> 
         <textarea rows="2" cols="40"></textarea>
    <br> <br> 
    <input name = "contacting" type = "checkbox" value = "contacting" onblur="myFunction()" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" /> <label>First time contacting me?  </label> 
    <br> 
    <p> <input type = "submit" value = "send" />

    </form>
    <style>
        div {
          text-align: left;
        }
      </style>
```

Comment: Try to share with js function validateForm you have for this as well.

Comment: This is the validate form  function  <script>
            function validateForm() {
              var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
              if (x == "" || x == null) {
                alert("Name must be filled out");
                return false;
              }
            }
            </script>

Comment: The submit event only exists on `<form>` not on controls within a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't have any 'code' in your question, just mark-up, but...

remove all of these:

```
onblur="myFunction()" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

For your first time checkbox, you could do something simple like this:

```
<input name="contacting" type="checkbox" value="contacting" onclick="if (this.checked){ alert('Thank you for contacting me!');}" /> <label>First time contacting me?  </label>
```

And your form tag should probably look like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

and in the `validationForm()` function you can catch return users like:

```
function validateForm() {
  // ... all your current validation stuff
  // if the validation doesn't check out, you can display an alert if you like, but must return false to prevent the form submit from going through
  // for example: if (!ok) return false
  // once you've validated all the inputs and are ready to submit...
  let name = document.querySelector('[name="name"]').value
  if (!document.querySelector('[name="contacting"]').checked) alert(`Welcome back ${name}!`);
  return true;
 }
```

**Note** inline event handlers like 'onsubmit' and 'onclick' are not recommended. The proper way to do these is to set them in your javascript after page load, like

```
document.querySelector('[name="contacting"]').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
if (e.target.getAttribute('checked')) alert('Thanks for ...');
})
```

Comment: Can I also add an alert when the user doesn't click on the box? like for example when the user doesn't click the box an alert comes up saying welcome

Comment: yes, but you'd do that in `validateForm()`, like my example.

Comment: also, I just fixed a line towards the end: `let name = document.querySelector('[name="name"]')` became `let name = document.querySelector('[name="name"]').value`